# Bootstrap navbar and mdb footer not working in single page

Tags: html, css, jsp, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I am trying to make webpages with `JSP` by using a **Bootstrap 4** fixed navbar and `mdbootstrap` footer.
But after including the footer to the page, the navbar style is not working.
What to do?

Navbar heading files:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>        

</head>
```

Footer heading files:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">           
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.11.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Main **JSP** page where both pages are included

```
<body>
    <jsp:include page="navbar.jsp"/>
    .
    . 
    .
    </footer> 
        <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>
    </footer>
```

Comment: HTML objects in browser can't have many roles. Only one role that applies last takes an effect. Having different profiles that were not loaded by the plugin can't make it pluggable over time. You can check the DOM for related HTML generated by the engine.